# Why is the browser blocked during the execution of a process in php?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, browser, request

I hope you can help me because ChatGPT has not succeeded hahaha.

I have the following code. It's long, but it works fine, and I really don't think it has any problems, just that it takes a long time to run.

The problem is that when I run my website, at least in the browser I'm using, it stops working, not even opening the web in another tab, nothing. I have to open another browser. (The browser is not blocked, my website is the one that does not load)

Any suggestions why this is happening. And how can I avoid it?

```
public function deep_cleaning_proccess()
{
    validate_ajax_session($this);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 86400); // 24 horas en segundos
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2G'); // 2 GB de memoria

    ignore_user_abort(true);

    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM logs WHERE id <> 1 AND tipo like 'borrar%'");
    $obj = $this->input->get('objeto');
    switch ($obj) {
        case 'all':
            break;
        case 'obras':
            break;
        case 'publicaciones':
            $directorio = "/av_web_disk_1.3/srv/av/assets/uploads/publicaciones";
            $archivos = scandir($directorio);
            sort($archivos);
            $progreso = array(
                "estado" => 0,
                "total" => count($archivos),
                "terminado" => false
            );
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO logs VALUES (1, 'borrar_publicacion', '" . json_encode($progreso) . "')
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tipo = 'borrar_publicacion', mensaje = '" . json_encode($progreso) . "'");
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($archivos); $i++) {
                if (is_dir($directorio . '/' . $archivos[$i])) {
                    $subcarpeta = $archivos[$i];
                    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(imagen, 'NullValue') AS imagen, COALESCE(url, 'NullValue') AS url, 
                                                COALESCE(pub_upload_folder, 'NullValue') AS pub_upload_folder, COALESCE(pub_upload_folder2, 'NullValue') AS pub_upload_folder2 
                                                FROM publicaciones p INNER JOIN imagenes i ON p.id = i.id_padre 
                                                WHERE p.id = '$subcarpeta;' AND i.estado <> 'papelera';")->result_array();
                    $lista_archivos = scandir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta);
                    if (count($result) > 0) {
                        $this->borrarImagenes($lista_archivos, $directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta, $result);
                        if (file_exists($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/pub_mid')) {
                            $lista_archivos = scandir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/pub_mid');
                            $this->borrarImagenes($lista_archivos, $directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/pub_mid', $result);
                        }
                        if (file_exists($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/pub_small')) {
                            $lista_archivos = scandir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/pub_small');
                            $this->borrarImagenes($lista_archivos, $directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/pub_small', $result);
                        }
                        if (file_exists($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/viewer')) {
                            $lista_archivos = scandir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/viewer');
                            foreach ($lista_archivos as $arch_borrar) {
                                if ($arch_borrar != "." && $arch_borrar != ".." && is_dir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/viewer/' . $arch_borrar)) {
                                    $borrar = true;
                                    if ($result[0]['pub_upload_folder'] == $arch_borrar || $result[0]['pub_upload_folder2'] == $arch_borrar) {
                                        $borrar = false;
                                    }
                                    if ($borrar) {
                                        if ($this->deleteDirectory($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/viewer/' . $arch_borrar)) {
                                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO logs (tipo, mensaje) 
                                            VALUES ('borrar_publicacion', 'Borrado: $directorio/$subcarpeta/viewer/$arch_borrar')");
                                        } else {
                                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO logs (tipo, mensaje) 
                                            VALUES ('borrar_publicacion', 'Error: $directorio/$subcarpeta/viewer/$arch_borrar')");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $progreso['estado'] = $i + 1;
                $this->db->query("UPDATE logs SET mensaje = '" . json_encode($progreso) . "'
                                    WHERE id = 1");
            }
            $progreso['terminado'] = true;
            $this->db->query("UPDATE logs SET mensaje = '" . json_encode($progreso) . "'
                                    WHERE id = 1");
            break;
        case 'articulos':
            break;
        case 'productos':
            $directorio = "/av_web_disk_1.3/srv/av/assets/uploads/productos";
            $archivos = scandir($directorio);
            sort($archivos);
            $progreso = array(
                "estado" => 0,
                "total" => count($archivos),
                "terminado" => false
            );
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO logs VALUES (1, 'borrar_productos', '" . json_encode($progreso) . "')
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tipo = 'borrar_productos', mensaje = '" . json_encode($progreso) . "'");
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($archivos); $i++) {
                if (is_dir($directorio . '/' . $archivos[$i]) && is_numeric($archivos[$i])) {
                    $subcarpeta = $archivos[$i];
                    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(imagen, 'NullValue') AS imagen, COALESCE(imagen_vertical, 'NullValue') AS imagen_vertical, 
                                                COALESCE(imagen_listados, 'NullValue') AS imagen_listados, COALESCE(url, 'NullValue') AS url, 
                                                COALESCE(cuerpo, 'NullValue') AS cuerpo, COALESCE(cuerpo_frontend, 'NullValue') AS cuerpo_frontend 
                                                FROM productos p INNER JOIN imagenes i ON p.id = i.id_padre WHERE p.id = $subcarpeta and i.estado<>'papelera';")->result_array();
                    $lista_archivos = scandir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta);
                    if (count($result) > 0) {
                        foreach ($lista_archivos as $arch_borrar) {
                            if (!is_dir($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/' . $arch_borrar)) {
                                $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($arch_borrar, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                                if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'webp') {
                                    $borrar = true;
                                    foreach ($result as $arch) {
                                        $nombre1 = strtolower(pathinfo($arch["imagen"], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
                                        $nombre2 = strtolower(pathinfo($arch["imagen_vertical"], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
                                        $nombre3 = strtolower(pathinfo($arch["imagen_listados"], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
                                        $nombre4 = strtolower(pathinfo($arch["url"], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
                                        $texto1 = strtolower($arch["cuerpo"]);
                                        $texto2 = strtolower($arch["cuerpo"]);
                                        if (
                                            strpos($arch_borrar, $nombre1 . '.') !== false
                                            || strpos($arch_borrar, $nombre2 . '.') !== false
                                            || strpos($arch_borrar, $nombre3 . '.') !== false
                                            || strpos($arch_borrar, $nombre4 . '.') !== false
                                            || strpos($texto1, $arch_borrar) !== false
                                            || strpos($texto2, $arch_borrar) !== false
                                        ) {
                                            $borrar = false;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if ($borrar) {
                                        if (unlink($directorio . '/' . $subcarpeta . '/' . $arch_borrar)) {
                                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO logs (tipo, mensaje) 
                                                VALUES ('borrar_productos', 'Borrado: $directorio/$subcarpeta/$arch_borrar')");
                                        } else {
                                            $error = error_get_last();
                                            $error = $error['message'];
                                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO logs (tipo, mensaje) 
                                                VALUES ('borrar_productos', 'Error: $directorio/$subcarpeta/$arch_borrar - $error')");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $progreso['estado'] = $i + 1;
                $this->db->query("UPDATE logs SET mensaje = '" . json_encode($progreso) . "'
                                                    WHERE id = 1");
            }
            $progreso['terminado'] = true;
            $this->db->query("UPDATE logs SET mensaje = '" . json_encode($progreso) . "'
                                                    WHERE id = 1");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the output is blocked during the execution, which is something you can actually change.  But in most cases its more to do with how the the server request and response works.  Than PHP.  For example you can see output streaming if you turn off the output buffering and a few other tricks, or you can stream output in the console.  The way the web is designed is not that way.  You can get around the server request response with AJAX and other things like that.

I wouldn't say it's something inherent to the PHP language.

Comment: You may be right, but the web stops responding, at first I thought it was the browser, but the browser works fine. Could it be that this instance of the server is blocked while it is running? That is why the server does not respond to more requests from that client, but it does from another browser.

Comment: Looking at this code and the amount of memory that you give it and time, there is a lot of DB operations and stuff.  It may be better to take another approach.    It may be hogging all the resources on the server and the DB could be locked etc.  For example as a night time CRON job or something that doesn't impact the site as much.

Comment: As I commented in the question, the code is fine, it terminates successfully. Only that it takes a long time, around 10 min, that's why I increase the memory, and the execution time. The problem is that during those 10 minutes the instance of the browser that sends it to run does not load the web until the process is finished.

Comment: Working with CRON is not a bad idea, I had it in mind. Although I would have liked to check it in real time.

Comment: My guess would be that it is table locking due to the modifications you are making.  During deletes and updates you cannot access the table or row ( depending on DB engine of course ).  If you try to access the table when a big delete is running the read must wait until it is complete to be ACID complient.  InooDB is better then MyIsam at this in some regards.  It may be preferable to make a new table and then rename it after dropping the old one.  Sometimes this can be significantly faster.  Build a modified copy, then replace the old table.  That way reads can progress and drop is fast.

Comment: But again something better not done during business hours or peak times.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253541/discussion-between-luis-miguel-molina-betancourt-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: It's possible to as this is AJAX if you run to many requests of this type you can actually use up all the DB connections... That's another possibility but you would see errors for this. In PHP admin you can see the processes that are running against the DB

Comment: When this happens look in PHP myadmin and check under Status menu and  Processes I believe will show you what queries are being ran and their status such as waiting for lock etc...  If you have error reporting turned on than that would be my guess, most other things will give you an error after a while.  This would just say something like the server failed to respond after a while as it's tied up waiting for access to the DB.

Comment: "Although I would have liked to check it in real time" - you've noted that this can take 10 minutes, so real time is already out the door. But a person can click a button in an interface, a task is added to the queue, cron is scheduled to run every minute and look for new tasks, and the browser then just polls the server for the current state.